# Dynamodb Scan vs Query when retrieving O(n) results

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I know the differences between Scanning a table with some filters and Querying a table by its `sort-key`.

I store time-series data on `dynamodb` tables, the `primary-key` is formed by `device_id` and `timestamp` (`partition` and `sort` keys respectively).

1. I have a table for each month.
2. I would like to retrieve all results of the past week.

How bad is scanning the current month's table and retrieving all results of the past week? I'm thinking it's not that bad as a quarter of the table are relevant results since a week = 1/4 month.

Given I had some smart indexing, could it be that retrieving `O(n)` table results be done in `o(n)`? (little `o`).

Comment: ah, i remember suggesting this data modelling to you.. the least you could have done is 'accepted' my answer

Comment: @ketan, your answer was not full and left unanswered question. I did push up your answer but not accepted it as it does not cover all the misunderstandings mentioned.

Not every answer should be accepted.